# Basics for making library project will have navigation function with map

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-maps-v2, android-library

I need to make a library project that will work as core part for any project.
I am familiar about how to [create library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) in android. My Question is not related to just creating library project but for basic things that has to be taken care for creating **map navigation library project**.

Following are few things that I have decided to achieve.

1. Any application project will use it as library project and that app doesn't have to use map because this library will have Google Map for operations.
2. This library will have some methods that will take list of route co-ordinates and other information to be displayed on the map.
3. The application will be using the map of the library project to access the things like methods and map properties to change the values.

**Questions**

1. Do I have to customize the Google Map view and use it as a view object as we customize the text-view, image-view etc.
2. Can I achieve this by creating Map Activity as base activity and let other apps to extend it.
3. Do I have to make it something like interfaces.

Any help will be appreciated in any way.

Comment: Frameworks designing is not as simple as you may think. Creating "BaseActivity", "XActivity", "RoboActivity", "SherlockActivity", "SQLiteActivity" as a base activity for extension is very poor. You are closely tied to this activity and what if user want to use some other functionality eg. your MapActivity and SherlockActivity with RoboActivity ? Library/framework should enable other applications to use them freely without any drawbacks. Interface is a MUST

Comment: That is why I am in confusion and not able to decide the which way will be best.

Comment: You should try to be independend from GoogleMap. This can be Achieved via some map interface or abstract class for handling maps. Unfortunately GoogleMap is tied with UI so it is harder to abstract such solution. There is no golden solution here and the best way is to TDD such project in order to know how such framework will be used. You know that best.